# RVIZ dockable panel plugins

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're in the process of converting our robots over to ROS and in the process, I would like to move my operator interface into ROS. rViz fits the bill for what I need, but only if I have ways to customize (i.e. plugins). I've written a plugin for a dockable panel that seems to work, but when it receives ROS messages, rViz crashes. I've recreated the code in a test case, and it receives the messages just fine, but debugging through rViz is proving very difficult.

I'm wondering if I'm just running into some limitations of the plugin development relating to it not really being ready for prime time. Has anyone had success with these?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43268/rviz-dockable-panel-plugins/) by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on 2012-11-01**:
fyi - I figured out my issue a while ago and forgot to update this posting. Thanks for all of the help.

**Comment by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on 2012-11-01**:
fyi - I figured out my issue a while ago and forgot to update this posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I developed a plug-in displaying PoseWithCovariance/Odometry messages but I haven't heard yet of someone extending the panels yet. My answer would be: yes the API should work but it is still very new.

As the API is yet unstable, I would split my development in two, the robot operator interface low-level function/generic implementation and a smaller part dedicated to plug this into the rviz current API. And be prepared to see the second part breaks as the API changes or other GUI being developed...

Could you send a backtrace of your crash + your plug-in code so that one can determine if this is a real bug or not?

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you should check the [rqt](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt) tool. It's still in quite early development but should suit better to what you want to achieve i.e. operator interface.

The tool is by definition a plugin based, and *rviz* itself could be one of the plugins to the tool.

Give it a try!

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1